# Combinatorics (Binary Tree)

Tags: combinatorics

A complete binary tree is a graph defined through the following recursive
definition.

Basis step: A single vertex is a complete binary tree.
Inductive step: If T1 and T2 are disjoint complete binary trees with
roots r1, r2, respectively, the the graph formed by starting with a root
r, and adding an edge from r to each of the vertices r1, r2 is also a
complete binary tree.

Prove that a complete binary tree has odd number of vertices.

I don't know where to start. This is supposed to be the hardest question in the chapter.

Comment: I know you are supposed to use induction, but thats about all I know.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Prove it by structural induction.

- Check that it’s true of the basis step. How many vertices does the basis tree have? Is that an odd number?
- Then show that the property of having an odd number of vertices is preserved by the recursion step. In other words, show that if $T_1$ and $T_2$ have odd numbers of vertices, then so does the new tree formed from them. If $T_1$ has $m$ vertices and $T_2$ has $n$ vertices, and you build a new tree $T$ according to the recursion step of the definition, how many vertices does $T$ have? Is that number guaranteed to be odd if $m$ and $n$ are both odd?

Once you’ve done both of those, you’re entitled to conclude that all complete binary trees have an odd number of vertices.

Comment: can u please do it step by step

Comment: @satjav: I’d prefer not to do that, because it’s really very straightforward. I’ve added more hints to my answer, though; see if you can answer either of the new questions that I added.

Comment: I think I got it. The basis tree has 1 vertex, an odd amount. The new tree formed by combining T1 and T2 is T1 + T2 + 1(the root). If T1 and T2 are both odd, then odd + odd + 1 is still odd.

Comment: @satjav: Yep, you’ve got it.